# How can I call `elem` with the map function in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, syntax

I have a list of lists

```
m = [l1, l2, l3]
l1 = ["A", "B"]
l2 = ["B", "X"]
etc.
```

and I want to call:

```
"A" `elem` l1
"A" `elem` l2 
etc.
```

to get something like `[True, False, True]`
How can I use `elem` in map

I tried to:

```
map `("A" `elem) m
```

but that gave me an error "couldn't match type"

Comment: What you did is correct, map ("A" \`elem\`) m

Comment: The backticks are written the wrong way, it is ``map ("A" `elem`) m``